# Specifying generic parameter to belong to a small set of types

Tags: generics, rust, traits, rust-macros

Is it possible with to constrain a generic parameter to be one of the select few types without figuring out what traits precisely define those type?  e.g.

```
impl<T> Data<T> where T == u32 || T == u64
```

Sometimes it's tedious to figure out what all traits to add to `where` to get the types you want, and sometimes one wouldn't want to allow a type even when it makes syntactic sense because of semantics.

Comment: *Sometimes it's tedious to figure out what all traits to add to where to get the types you want* — sometimes it's tedious to get code that explicitly states its dependencies and doesn't mysteriously fail when some arbitrary type somewhere decides to rename a method; and I consider that a **good thing**. Rust is not Go. Automatically inferring membership in a trait is not a good thing, as the *signature* of a function is not the only thing that makes up the contract inferred by a trait. There are aspects that cannot be expressed in code, and that's why a human has to apply a trait.

Comment: I agree. My particular use case here is not one of those times, because it make one have to look deeper under the hood than a high level use case should require in theory (i.e. a numeric trait for integers without using an external crate), for example, `1..n` requires a trait, the type signature for a `std::ops::Add` that can support `a + b + c` starts to go deeper, and then you realize trait for `Zero` is not in stable. FWIW i share the sentiment on `go`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a marker trait for the types you want to support:

```
trait DataSupported {}

impl DataSupported for u64 {}
impl DataSupported for u32 {}

impl<T> Data<T> where T: DataSupported {}
```

As [Pavel Strakhov mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381185/specifying-generic-parameter-to-belong-to-a-small-set-of-types/42381330#comment71932609_42381330), if you need to use this trait for a few `impl`s and you need other trait bounds, then you can just make those traits as bounds of your marker trait instead, which will keep your `impl`s terse:

```
trait DataSupported: Num + Debug {}
```

Comment: Actually this causes problems as the compiler doesn't infer the common set of traits implemented by these types, and so you have to put each bound individually

Comment: You can do something like `trait DataSupported : Display + Debug {}` and write all traits you need there. You won't have to list those traits in `impl`s.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov thanks, I'll update my answer with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a macro to add implementations based on a list of types:

```
macro_rules! data_impl {
    ($($t: ty),+) => {
        $(
            impl Data<$t> {
                // methods go here
            }
        )+
    }
}

data_impl!(u32, u64, i32, i64);
```

It's probably worth adding `#[allow(dead_code)]` to each method to prevent warnings, since you'll be defining lots of specialised methods that may not be used in your application if you don't use them for *every* possible type. This is exactly the same thing that the compiler does anyway if you define methods over a parameter `T` (a process called monomorphisation). The difference is that the macro-generated methods are defined during the compiler's parse step (before linting) while monomorphisation happens later in the pipeline.